# Azure website + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure

I am starting my Azure Project. I did a website to Run Wordpress. Migrating from a previous host entity.

I use mysql, the ClearDb azure has is very limited and expensive $75 p month just because i need views and triggers ( only available on the dedicated server plan) its SAD. I Then created my MySql in Amazon RDS.

I did some latency tests, and the fact that Mysql being Closer to the Website region helps alot to reduce latency.

But still, my wordpress navigation seems slow! The first time is terrible, around 4 seconds. The next ones a bit better but nothing compared to my previous host of around 200ms!

Is this because of mysql being accessed by remote and not being in the same "data center" ? or is this because another thing like the "hot and cold" websites concept of Azure!? ( because even secondary calls are slow)...

I am starting to realize Azure is not Good for Websites with PHP + MYSQL.

I like the look and feel of Azure UI and Website concept but this is Very disappointing from azure not having a self MYSQL Structure.

Comment: Using now https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-optimize-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Latency is a problem. Before assume that Azure is good or not, try a new thing. Create an azure virtual machine and install mysql in there. Then, edit your connection string to point to your VM. Also, install a plugin cache because wordpress execute a lot of queries in your database.

Another option: did you try the Scalable WordPress available through Azure Marketplace?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/wordpress/scalablewordpress/

Comment: Out wordpress has some customizations, dont know if that would still work, and migrate code, could be a hassle... But i will try the VM and will report back. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that you'll create a VM, give a try do WAMP or LAMP. In other words, put your wordpress in there too.

Comment: I tried VM running mysql and website separate, and the minimum latency was 0.06/0.07/0.08 seconds in that setup, Before (using mysql at Amazon) was 0.07/0.08/0.09 seconds

Comment: Well but that is not intented. I want to isolate services. I did test a new Vm with apt-get mysql etc.. and then, the latency result is that its almost the same... a little better  though,  before i got 0.08 or 0.09 and not i get around 0.07 sometimes 0.06..

Comment: Just a side not, even with that latency the site is slower, somehow compared to my previous hoster. I see many latency  peaks of 2 seconds , 3 seconds sometimes.. its strange

Answer (score 0):

@Miguel, I agree with Thiago.

I think you can install MYSQL database on VM and connect it with your Wordpress website. 
In this scenarios, I suggest you can use some tool to find the items which takes more times, such as [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) . It is useful for further steps.

At the same time, you can try to optimize your database,compress Images and so on. I recommend you can refer to this blog about [how to improve the WP site performances.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site-on-azure-websites/)

By the way, Azure will unload your site if it is idle for the standard 20 minute timeout, which can cause slow responses for the initial site users after it is unloaded. You could enable the "always on" feature if you think it is necessary.

Comment: i did enable the always on, for this mysql VM server and the Website (wordpress) too. But the thing is the connection between Mysql and Wordpress has latency, its not just about the files i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using persistent connections from your WordPress site to MySQL database. That can decrease latency times by decreasing time to create a connection and instead reuse existing connections.

Answer (score 0):

**The MySQL latency is an issue and there is probably not much we can do about it since the DB call has to be made further than to the localhost - simple as that.**

1) **If you need Azure for your MySQL driven eapp, use Microsoft's VM** which is running quite reliably and where you can install PHP/MySQL on the same machine - speedy but relatively pricey. So far the only production acceptable solution for MySQL I found.

2) **Don't use Azure if you need fast MySQL connections.** We have tons of MS apps running in azure with various versions of MSSQL - and they all running relatively fine. So far I did not find fast solution for MySQL. Therefore, I am still using Linode for the PHP/MySQL apps. Their speed and service is superb (*I am not getting anything from Linode for this recommendation :)* and it is quite inexpensive in comparison to Azure in this case.